# Automating a counting bot in a browser

Tags: python

I am trying to create a script that counts in the phone browser.

I want to search phone numbers, but have it count at the end of the phone number to count up from 00-99. So it will ask for the phone number except for the last two, then search it on the website.

This is a computer based script.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import time
import webbrowser
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#what number you are searching
number = input('enter number: ')

#browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
webbrowser.open('https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/phone')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/form')


#counting
count = 0
while count <= 100:
        print(str(number) + str(count).zfill(2))
        count = count + 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: what do you want to do? you want to extract phone numbers from a website?

Comment: It's not too clear what you are trying to do here. Is this python code supposed to run  on a mobile OS? If so, I don't believe or expect that `webbrowser.open()` will work

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi i want to atuomative search phone numbers on a website that adds the twop numbers at the end of a phone number

Comment: Instead of bothering with updating the form, simply insert the phone number to the URL to get the results.  Notice how if you enter the example number `818-444-3214` into the form, you will be directed to `https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/818-444-3214`

Comment: @HymnsForDisco how can i count on the url though? to go from 818-444-3215

Comment: @bolticle A url is just a string, the end of your example code here is already capable of counting up through phone number strings, you just need to append that to the base url string.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco can u write the first code i am confused how could i count a web.browser.open

Comment: @bolticle `webbrowser.open` simply takes a string as an argument for the URL. Your while loop is already able to form a string with a counting number like this at the end, you just need to pass that string to `webbrowser.open` as an argument